# Сохранение и открытие PDF файла из базы данных

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, jdbc

Нужна помощь, как можно загрузить PDF файл в БД MySQL средствами JDBC и также потом загрузить его с БД и открыть в программе для просмотра PDF файлов на смартфоне, помогите пожалуста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Можно сохранить файл pdf в память, а его путь сохранить в базу данных.
2. Можно конвертировать пдф в массив байт и попробовать запихнуть в базу этот массив (но это не есть хорошо по причине, указанной выше) 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970964/how-to-save-the-pdf-file-generated-into-mysql-database-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Не храните файлы, картинки и т.д. в БД, храните ссылки на конкретные файлы в сети интернет.
Все `BLOB` данные только неоправданно увеличивают размер БД и приводят к фрагментации.

Вам нужно сохранять файлы на сервере, и БД записывать путь к конкретному файлу. После того, как понадобился конкретный файл - делается запрос к БД, чтобы найти путь к файлу, и уже по конкретной ссылке забираете на клиенте файл!

Comment: То есть это сделать невозможно?

Comment: @user221117 возможно всё. Но будет ли это правильно?

Comment: Ну мне так нужно зделать